# Как стилизовать капчу от Google - reCAPTCHA V2

Tags: javascript, css, recaptcha

Стили подтягиваются через скрипт во фрейм, динамически.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27713505/5441700

Comment: Коротко - никак, максимум вы можете изменить размер видимой области с помощью scale

Comment: Итак, действительно, никак.